# How to retrive and store the individual element of a map in java

Tags: java

I have a map object where I have a list of values.  Now I want to iterate the values and store individual object items to  individual variables so that I can insert the variables into database. I am successful to iterate the values from the map. But now I want to store individual values to individual elements. Here is my code...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    Map rec = d.getRecord();
    for (int j = 0; j < rec.size(); j++) {
        Collection c = rec.values();
        Iterator itr = c.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the output is

```
Fri Jan 18 23:45:07 IST 2013
7118492
Mon Dec 31 14:25:43 IST 2012
+919748675483
+919748183326

Fri Jan 18 23:45:07 IST 2013
7118492
Mon Dec 31 14:25:43 IST 2012
+919748675483
+919748183326
```

Now I want to store `Fri Jan 18 23:45:07 IST 2013` to some variable, `7118492` to some variable and so on.

Comment: What's it a map *of*?

Comment: So access it like you'd access any other map, although I'm not convinced you answered what I actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the map you can do this:

```
    Map<String, String>map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Entry<String, String>entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        entry.getKey();
        entry.getValue();
    }
```

`getKey()`  returns the keyvalue from your map, and `getValue()` returns the value which is associated to that key in your map. It is the same as if you would do `value = map.get(key);`

Comment: will getKey give me  the key of  Fri Jan 18 23:45:07 IST 2013???because i think that the set i provided belongs to 0 key and the 2 nd one belongs to 1 key

Comment: The entry is exactly one key/value pair from your map. I don't know your map though, or what you try to do with your loop. Maybe you could update your question with what you are trying to achieve, then it would be easier to tell what you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do this, as you can access each item from the map as you need.

But if you simply prefer a list of items, you could add the values to a list, and then use each item from the list as you require.

e.g.

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(rec.values());
for (String s : list) {
    // do something with s
}
```